# Error TooManyProviderTokenUpdates starts coming from APNS

Tags: apple-push-notifications

We are facing `TooManyProviderTokenUpdates error` very frequently while sending normal and silent push notification to apns from our server and frequency of silent notification is around 8-9 hours and for normal it is around 30 minutes. We are using pushy java library to communicate with **APNS** server. My push library version is 11.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my solution.

Just sharing the link, I got from Apple forum. Might help you.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86288